# Connection closed exception when using Oracle Weblogic's JNDI datasource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc, weblogic12c, jdbctemplate

I'm making use of Oracle Weblogic's (12.1.3) JNDI datasource for connection pooling. The max idle time for a connection is set to 30 seconds in the admin console. But, there is this method that takes more than a minute to complete, which results in the connection getting automatically closed.
My problem is that I have set autoCommit as false, and I'm unable to rollback the transaction in case of an Exception. I'm making use of pure JDBC. I tried using Spring's JdbcTemplate, surprisingly there is no Connection related issue when I'm making use of the @Transactional annotation.

Is there a technique using which I can keep the connections that I get from the Weblogic's JNDI datasource alive for more than 30 seconds, without modifying the configurations in the admin console?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to ask is that, is there a technique using which I can keep the connections that I get from the Weblogic's JNDI datasource alive for more than 30 seconds, without modifying the configurations in the admin console?

Comment: the timeout can be configured in the datasource at WebLogic's console, however, it seems that your connection is being used by another thread therefore the @Transancional is maintained the TX atomic and isolated.

Comment: Is there a way to override the timeout at the code level?